# Why float :right not working in css3?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I need to display label on right side as shown in image. I am able to make header. But I am not able to display header labels on right side. I already use

```
float: right!important
```

Second thing when I change the browser width to 600px it change the label into dropdown. How is this possible? I search google and find there is a way to use media query. I am able to add this but how to change right label to dropdown?

Here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpoaXG

```
    #menubar li{
        display: inline;
        padding:0.5em;
        font-size:1.5em;
        color :red
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        body {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    }
#menubar{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your wrapping `div` an ID (such as `menubarCont`) and add this to your CSS:

```
#menubarCont {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaKdxw)

Comment: thanks for solution ..but how to change label into drop down ..as shown in image when screen size is 600

Comment: You can use this also '#menubarCont{position:fixed;right:x%;}'

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `#menubar` is within small parent element. The parent element should have set `width:100%` or something like this. When the parent element is too small, then there is no place for floating

Comment: thanks for solution ..but how to change label into drop down ..as shown in image when screen size is 600